# How do I break out of this loop? java

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I want to be able to get the user to either start a new round or end the game. Every time I answer no when asked if I want to continue(n/y) it does not end the game.

Also how do I count the number of rounds played? Also the private static variables are given in the assignment I did not make them.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class GuessingGame {

    private static final int MIN_NUMBER = 1;
    private static final int MAX_NUMBER = 205;
    private static final int QUIT_VALUE = -1;
    private static final int LOSE_VALUE = -2;
    private static final int MAX_GAMES = 4;
    private static final int MAX_GUESSES = 10;
    private static final int HINT_THRESHOLD = 5;
    private static final int BACKDOOR_VALUE = -314;

    private static final String NOPE_MSG = "nope...";
    private static final String NOPE_NOPE_MSG
            = "you've already guessed that wrong guess...";
    private static final String INVALID_INPUT_BEGIN
            = "*** invalid input -- ";
    private static final String INVALID_INPUT_LESS_MIN_MSG
            = INVALID_INPUT_BEGIN + "must be greater than " + (MIN_NUMBER - 1);
    private static final String INVALID_INPUT_GREATER_MAX_MSG
            = INVALID_INPUT_BEGIN + "must be less than " + (MAX_NUMBER + 1);
    private static final String INVALID_INPUT_YN_MSG
            = INVALID_INPUT_BEGIN + "must be n or y";
    private static final String WINNER_MSG
            = "you're a winner... # of guesses: ";
    private static final String LOSER_MSG
            = "too many guesses entered... the number was ";
    private static final String QUITTER_MSG
            = "you're a quitter... the number was ";
    private static final String MAX_GAMES_PLAYED_MSG
            = "you've played the maximum number (" + MAX_GAMES + ") of games";
    private static final String ENTER_GUESS_PROMPT
            = "enter a guess between " + MIN_NUMBER + " and " + MAX_NUMBER
            + " (" + QUIT_VALUE + " to quit): ";
    private static final String PLAY_AGAIN_PROMPT
            = "Do you want to play again (n or y)? ";

    private static final String BOLD_BEGIN = "*** ";
    private static final String BOLD_END = " ***";
    private static final String PLAY_MSG = " playing the CSC" + MAX_NUMBER
            + " guessing game." + BOLD_END;
    private static final String WELCOME_MSG
            = BOLD_BEGIN + "Hello! Have fun" + PLAY_MSG;
    private static final String THANKS_MSG
            = BOLD_BEGIN + "Thanks for" + PLAY_MSG;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PlayGame();
    }

    static Random rng = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    static Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    static int n = MIN_NUMBER + rng.nextInt(MAX_NUMBER);
    static int guess;
    static int guessCounter = 0;

    static boolean endStart = true;

    public static void PlayGame() {

        System.out.println(WELCOME_MSG);
        while (endStart = true) {
            do {

                System.out.println();
                System.out.print(ENTER_GUESS_PROMPT);
                guess = stdin.nextInt();
                guessCounter = guessCounter + 1;

                if (guess < MIN_NUMBER && guess != BACKDOOR_VALUE
                        && guess != QUIT_VALUE) {
                    System.out.println(INVALID_INPUT_LESS_MIN_MSG + "\n");
                }
                if (guess > MAX_NUMBER) {
                    System.out.println(INVALID_INPUT_GREATER_MAX_MSG + "\n");
                }
                if (guess == BACKDOOR_VALUE) {
                    System.out.println(n);
                }

                if (guess == QUIT_VALUE) {
                    System.out.println(QUITTER_MSG + n);
                    System.out.println(PLAY_AGAIN_PROMPT);
                    String val = scan.next();
                    if (val.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                        PlayGame();
                    }
                    if (val.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                        System.out.println(THANKS_MSG);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (guessCounter == MAX_GUESSES) {
                    System.out.println(LOSER_MSG + n
                            + PLAY_AGAIN_PROMPT);
                    String val = scan.next();
                    if (val.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                        PlayGame();
                    }
                    if (val.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                        System.out.println(THANKS_MSG);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (guess > MIN_NUMBER || guess < MAX_NUMBER) {
                    if (guess != n || guess == BACKDOOR_VALUE) {
                        System.out.println(NOPE_MSG);
                    }
                    if (guess == n) {
                        System.out.println(WINNER_MSG + guessCounter);

                        System.out.println(PLAY_AGAIN_PROMPT);
                        String val = scan.next();
                        if (val.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                            PlayGame();
                        }
                        if (val.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                            System.out.println(THANKS_MSG);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } while (guess > MIN_NUMBER || guess < MAX_NUMBER);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: too many lines of code and too many questions. you break out of a loop with break.

Comment: @efekctive I know I can use a break but I want to know how to break out of a specific loop.

Comment: Then reduce the sample code. if you know how to break once, the second time is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a `boolean` and you can check with it in your loop for example :

```
boolean test = true;
do{
   //your code
   //if you want to break you can change the test variable
   ...
     if(val.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){ 
         System.out.println(THANKS_MSG);
         test = false;
         break();
     } 
   ..
}while(guess > MIN_NUMBER || guess < MAX_NUMBER || test);
```

So if your condition or test is false you will break from your loop.

Answer (score 0):

`while(endStart == true) or while( endStart )` would look better, whereas while(endStart = true), by no means comparison of endStart variable, plus you are RECURSING INDEFINITELY Everytime you call PlayGame() once gain, in the PlayGame() method, and it keeps getting crazier

Answer (score 0):

You Can use a break with label, Labeled break statement is used to terminate the outer loop, the loop should be labeled for it to work. For an example follow this,

```
 loop1:
 for(){
   ...
    for(){
       ....
       break loop1;
    }
 }
```